# How to auto select the next date in the second calender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 calenders on my form

- DateFrom1 and DateTo1
- DateFrom2 and DateTo2
- DateFrom3 and DateTo3

My calenders always open by using today date, however, I don't need it.

I want that when my user select `20/2/2013` from `DateFrom1` (calender) and after that when my user click on `DateTO1` (calender) it must autoselect `21/2/2013` in open calender.

And if he clicks on `DateFrom2` (calender) it should show with auto select (`22/2/2013`) in the calender view.

How can I do this in asp.net?

Comment: i am using "CalendarExtender"

Answer (score 2):

On [Calander.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event you can specify the SelectedDate for the other calander to next day using `.AddDays(1)` in [SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx).

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  DateTo1.SelectedDate = DateFrom1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: i am using "CalendarExtender"